# Bundling shell commands in NodeJs spawn

Tags: node.js, shell

I wish to run commands like `NODE_ENV=production node server` or `cd ~/app/cms; npm test` with [NodeJs spawn](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

First can be achieved with

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'
start = spawn 'node', ['server'], process.env
```

But how can I achieve the second?

**Updated**:
In case someone have similar problem, here is my example in coffeescript:

```
testCode = ->
    testCore = spawn 'npm', ['test']
    testCore.stderr.on 'data', (data) -> console.log() process.stderr.write data.toString()
    testCore.stdout.on 'data', (data) -> print data.toString()
    testCore.on 'exit', ->
        path = require 'path'
        process.chdir path.join(__dirname, "app", "linkParser")
        testModule = spawn 'npm', ['test']
        testModule.stderr.on 'data', (data) -> process.stderr.write data.toString()
        testModule.stdout.on 'data', (data) -> print data.toString()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
path = require "path"
process.chdir path.join(process.env.HOME, "app", "cms")
spawn "npm", "test"
```

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_process_chdir_directory

Comment: Thanks, for reference, I modified your solution a bit to solve my issue, added example in question.

Answer (score 1):

I received the `ENOENT` error while attempting to call `cd` from the child process.

@Peter Lyons answer was helpful. After reading more documentation on spawn, I decided to go with the following to keep the parent process working directory clean:

**Coffeescript:**

```
spawn "npm", "test",
  cwd: path.join(process.env.HOME, "app", "cms")
```

**JavaScript:**

```
spawn("npm", "test", { cwd: path.join(process.env.HOME, "app", "cms") });
```

By experience I found you can also pass just the string:

**Coffeescript:**

```
spawn "npm", "test", path.join(process.env.HOME, "app", "cms")
```

**JavaScript:**

```
spawn("npm", "test", path.join(process.env.HOME, "app", "cms"));
```

Check out [spawn docs](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) for more info.