# Implement paging in a NodeJS repl

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

How would one go about adding paging to the NodeJS REPL? I'm building a simple command line app in NodeJS and want to be able to page through output (similar to how the MySQL console lets you page through query results) using `less` or `more` as filter programs.

I don't necessarily need the search functionality: just the pausing of the scroll (so I don't have to scroll up to see what's happened) and the ability to cancel the output (so I can quit the output on page 2 of 2000).

Comment: It would be nice, but currently, I run node.js REPL in `Gnu screen`, where `Ctrl-a [` bring into copy mode, then scroll back and search is possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bundling shell commands in NodeJs spawn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764051/bundling-shell-commands-in-nodejs-spawn)